# Why is my grid offset in this example?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a randomly occupied grid with matplotlib. The grid looks offset from the blocks by a random amount:

[image: The grid]

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Make a 10x10 grid...
nrows, ncols = 10,10
# Fill the cells randomly with 0s and 1s
image = np.random.randint(2, size = (nrows, ncols))

# Make grid
vgrid = []
for i in range(nrows + 1):
    vgrid.append((i - 0.5, i - 0.5))
    vgrid.append((- 0.5, 9.5))

hgrid = []
for i in range(ncols + 1):
    hgrid.append((- 0.5, 9.5))
    hgrid.append((i - 0.5, i - 0.5))

row_labels = range(nrows)
col_labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'j']

plt.matshow(image, cmap='Greys')
for i in range(11):
    plt.plot(hgrid[2 * i], hgrid[2 * i + 1], 'k-')
    plt.plot(vgrid[2 * i], vgrid[2 * i + 1], 'k-')

plt.axis([-0.5, 9.5, -0.5, 9.5])
plt.xticks(range(ncols), col_labels)
plt.yticks(range(nrows), row_labels)

plt.show()
```

The problem seems to happen when I enforce a plot area; this line:

```
plt.axis([-0.5, 9.5, -0.5, 9.5])
```

Also, please feel free to suggest a better method. I am new to pyplot.

Comment: This should be fixed by https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/5718 which should be merged for mpl2.0

Answer (score 4):

You can use `plt.grid()` to plot the axes grid. Unfortunately it won't solve the issue. The misalignment of the grid is a [known issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1441) for `imshow` (a function that is called by `matshow`).

I suggest to play with the figure size and the linewidth of the grid, until you get something acceptable.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5));

nrows, ncols = 10,10
image = np.random.randint(2, size = (nrows, ncols))
row_labels = range(nrows)
col_labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'j']
plt.matshow(image, cmap='Greys',fignum=1,interpolation="nearest")

#set x and y ticks and labels
plt.xticks(range(ncols), col_labels)
plt.yticks(range(nrows), row_labels);

#set minor axes in between the labels
ax=plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks([x-0.5 for x in range(1,ncols)],minor=True )
ax.set_yticks([y-0.5 for y in range(1,nrows)],minor=True)
#plot grid on minor axes
plt.grid(which="minor",ls="-",lw=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, changing the line width for the grid lines seems to be a quick and dirty fix but if it's the only option then I'll try to live with it. Hopefully the issue will be resolved soon.

Answer (score 1):

This is [known behavior](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Misalignment-imshow-vs-grid-lines-td39592.html) because, by default, `matshow()` calls `imshow()` with the argument `interpolation="nearest"`.  You should get better results by overriding the argument manually:

```
plt.matshow(image, cmap='Greys', interpolation="none")
```

Comment: I actually got better results with "nearest` than "none", with inline plots in the IPython notebook. I think it depends on the size of the figure and how you display/save it.

Comment: Yep, if it's screen aliasing then bigger images are often better.  No idea if that plays well with IPython though.